# MVC separated layout in created area

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this structure, the top listed is 1 area:

[image: Text]

I want Area have his own shared _Layout, problem it is that it always takes the project _Layout.

That's the code of _ViewStart of the area:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutTyre24.cshtml";
}
```

But it says that can't find this.
What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Replace Layout value like below in _ViewStart

```
Layout = "~/Areas/{AddAreaNameHere}/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```